# Is there any function that satisfies the limit exists?

Tags: limits

Is there any function that satisfies the limit below exists ?

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=0
$$

Comment: Yes. The function must be getting small quickly. Try $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: $f(n)=\frac 1 {n!}$ then $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac1{n+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $f(x) = x^{-x}$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x+1)^{-(x+1)}}{x^{-x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-x} = 0\cdot e^{-1} = 0$$